# Is it possible to exit app without closing activity

Tags: android, android-studio, android-activity

Is it possible to open straight to last activity in app when previously pressed the back button ?
just like when pressed home button the app will straight to open last activity.

using `finish()` and `finishAffinity()` not working because it will close the activity

Answer (score 0):

If you finish the previous activity . There is no way you could go back there.

Start the new activity without finishing the previous one. Finish should work

Comment: but how about when home button pressed ?, when the app is opened again its go to the last activity right

Comment: I think what you mean is minimize the app ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use SharedPreferences to save the last Activity and run when you want. you can save your parameter too